# How to make a function that calls an object method on every object in a list?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to be able to invoke a given method name on all objects in a given list. Say the method I want to call is jump, and I have a list of people who have varying jump methods. Some jump at different angles, others higher or lower etc etc. But I want to call the jump method on all of my list of basketball players in order to see who gets to be on the team.

```
function doMethodToList(list, method){
   for(var i = 0; i< list.length; i++){
      list[i].method();
   }
} 
var roster = [new Jack(), new Jill(), new Brody()];
doMethodToList(roster, "jump");
```

I am thinking something like the above code should work. However it would throw an error when calling `doMethodToList(roster, "jump")` because I am trying to use a string as a method. Any ideas how to make this function work? Maybe am I thinking of this all wrong? Answers highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do the following in your loop:

```
if (list[i][method]) list[i][method]();
```

Comment: That 'if' is a really good idea. That will save me from running through a list of lists that contain objects with a certain method type. Now I just run through all objects and see if they have the method. If so it runs. If not it is not an error.

Comment: You could also add a type check to be sure it's a function : `if (list[i][method] && typeof  list[i][method] === "function") list[i][method]();` just in case some of your objects have properties that are not methods but with the same name

Answer (score 4):

To access a property of an object with a string you use square bracket notation

```
function doMethodToList(list, method){
   for(var i = 0; i< list.length; i++){
      list[i][method]();// <-- here
   }
} 
var roster = [new Jack(), new Jill(), new Brody()];
doMethodToList(roster, "jump");
```